# Call to a member function addEagerConstraints() on integer

Tags: laravel, eloquent, eager-loading

I tried to eager load a relation:

```
$tournaments = Tournament::with('numCompetitors')->latest()->paginate(config('constants.PAGINATION'));
```

My relation in Tournament returns an integer:

```
public function numCompetitors()
{
    return $this->competitors()->count(); // it returns 24
}
```

With that I get:

```
Call to a member function addEagerConstraints() on integer
```

I don't understand why is it failing.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You're doing it wrong. If you want to count relationship, use [`withCount()`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent-relationships#counting-related-models) with properly defined relationship:

```
Tournament::withCount('competitors')->latest()->paginate(config('constants.PAGINATION'));
```

> If you want to count the number of results from a relationship without actually loading them you may use the withCount method, which will place a `{relation}_count` column on your resulting models.

https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent-relationships#counting-related-models

Comment: Great! Exactly what I forgot ! Tx!